# VBA Userform Dropdown list, populating other fields

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a user form in excel, VBA, which has ComboBox5 as the starting point.
When the user drops this down, I want it to look back to an excel work sheet (FaultLog - range B:L) and then to autopopulate the textboxes.
Similar to how VLookup works in a worksheet.
Is this possible?

Have tried this...

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change() 

    Me.TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox5.Value, Sheets("FaultLog").Range("B2:J9999"), 2, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Have tried this...Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()
Me.TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox5.Value, Sheets("FaultLog").Range("B2:J9999"), 2, False)
End Sub

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code you have tried there. It will be easier for the community to help you.

Comment: Do you get an error when your code runs? If so, what is the error number and description?

Answer (score 0):

This should work but you'll need to change `.Value` to `.Caption` in a Userform.

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change() 

    Me.TextBox1.Caption = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox5.Value, Sheets("FaultLog").Range("B2:J9999"), 2, False)

End Sub
```